# Are they going to interfere with each other?

Tags: javascript, api, rest

```
const getUser = (userName) => {
  const controller = new AbortController();
  const { signal } = controller;
  
  {...some fetch code to a url and assign to promise variable }
    
  return [
    promise,
    controller.abort.bind(controller),
  ];
};
```

```
const userOne = getUser('userone');
const userTwo = getUser('usertwo');
```

Is userOne and userTwo somehow going to interfere with each other when I call abort on one of them due to both of them use the same controller(AbortController())?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You didn't show how exactly the signal gets passed into `fetch`, but that actually shouldn't matter much: each time `getUser` function is invoked, a new instance of `AbortController` is created. That means both `fetch` requests, `abort` functions, and `signals` created with each call of `getUser` are independent.